# Error using º and ' in bibliography entry title

Tags: bibliographies, errors, unicode

I have been trying for a while to incorporate a bibliographic entry ([Escartin et. al 2010: Globally aligned photomosaic of the Lucky Strike hydrothermal vent field (Mid‐Atlantic Ridge, 37°18.5′N): Release of georeferenced data, mosaic construction, and viewing software](https://doi.org/10.1029/2008GC002204)) to a text that I am working on. However i cannot compile because of the symobls `º` and `'` in the title. Here is a minimal verifaible example (see it also in [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/ynrynkgmjmgd)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    hyperref=true,
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=99,
    maxbibnames=99,
    giveninits=false,
    sorting=none,
    abbreviate=false,
    uniquename=init,
    parentracker=true,
    url=false,
    doi=true,
    isbn=false,
    eprint=false,
    backref=true,
    sortcites=true,
]{biblatex}

 \begin{filecontents}{bibliography_file.bib}
@article{Escartin2008,
author = {Escart{\'{i}}n, J. and Garc{\'{i}}a, R. and Delaunoy, O. and Ferrer, J. and Gracias, N. and Elibol, A. and Cufi, X. and Neumann, L. and Fornari, D. J. and Humphris, S. E. and Renard, J.},
doi = {10.1029/2008GC002204},
isbn = {1525-2027},
issn = {15252027},
journal = {Geochemistry, Geophysics, Geosystems},
keywords = {Hydrothermal field,Lucky strike,Mid-ocean ridge,MoMAR,Photomosaic},
number = {12},
pages = {1--17},
title = {{Globally aligned photomosaic of the Lucky Strike hydrothermal vent field (Mid-Atlantic Ridge, 37°18.5′N): Release of georeferenced data, mosaic construction, and viewing software}},
volume = {9},
year = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography_file.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

In \cite{Escartin2008} the title produces an error.

\medskip

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which produces this output:

[image]

You can see how the title has an error. Can somebody tell me how can I solve this so I can provide a proper citation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are completely right.

Comment: If you are already using unicode chars like `°` and `′`, you might as well go all in and write `García` instead of `Garc{\'{i}}a`. You will also want to make sure to load `hyperref` last (definitely after `biblatex` and `csquotes`).

Comment: Well, it is like this as the bibentry is exported automatically from Mendeley. Thank you for the hyperref tip.

Comment: Speaking of `hyperref`. The `biblatex` setting `hyperref=true` is for most people no better than the default `hyperref=auto`. The only difference between the two is that the former issues a warning if `hyperref` is not loaded. In both cases you get links if and only if `hyperref` is also loaded. `parentracker=true,` and `giveninits=false,` are the default values, so need to be explicitly set, the same goes for `doi=true`.